# R Code for some .png for a visual search task

Tags: r, search, png

I would like to carry out a psychological study where test subjects have to react in a visual search experiment on the computer when a certain stimulus is presented.  I would like to use Rstudio to create several images.  In the pictures, black “X” and “+” as well as red “X” and red “+” should appear in different places and in different numbers.  For example, the test person is asked to press a key if the red “X” is there.  It is important that the target, i.e. the red “X”, always appears somewhere different (never in the same place in a row) or sometimes does not appear at all, i.e. randomly.

I tried to play around with ggplot but i think its not right.

Comment: Code you tried, please...

Comment: plot(x, y, pch = 3, 4, col = “black“ cex = 3, lwd = 3)

Comment: for random volor maybe something like this: randomColor()

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
The function below will plot `n` points at random, waiting `wait` seconds if the point is not red. If it is red and the user takes too long to click on the plot area then the result is considered wrong and `ok[i]` is set to the empty string `""`. This is tested in the end, a result of 0.75 means I got 3/4 of the red crosses in due time.

```
test <- function(n, wait = 3, off = TRUE) {
  # random coordinates
  x <- runif(n)
  y <- runif(n)
  # random color and point character
  clr <- c("black", "red")[sample(2, n, TRUE)]
  pch <- sample(3:4, n, TRUE)
  
  # return value
  ok <- clr
  for(i in seq.int(n)) {
    plot(
      x[i], y[i], 
      pch = pch[i], col = clr[i], 
      cex = 3, lwd = 3,
      xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1),
      xlab = "", ylab = "",
      xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",
      asp = 1L
    )
    start <- proc.time()[3]
    repeat{
      if(clr[i] == "red") {
        locator(1L)
        ellapsed <- proc.time()[3] - start
        if(ellapsed > wait) ok[i] <- ""
        break
      }
      ellapsed <- proc.time()[3] - start
      if(ellapsed > wait) break
    }
  }
  if(off) dev.off(which = dev.cur())
  ok
}

set.seed(2023)

result <- test(10)
result
# [1] "black" "black" "red"   ""      "black" "red"   "red"   "black" "black" "black"

# ratio of right clicks on "red" on total clicks not on "black"
# (when a click is not on "black" it can be a click on "red" that took too long)
sum(result == "red")/sum(result != "black")
# [1] 0.75
```

---

## Edit

To answer to the comments, this function accepts a number of points or, if missing, chooses at random a number of points `n` and plots them all, just one red, the others black. Then waits for the user to click near one of the points and returns the corresponding color.

```r
test2 <- function(n, max.points = 5L, off = TRUE) {
  if(missing(n)) n <- sample(max.points, 1L)
  # random coordinates
  x <- runif(n)
  y <- runif(n)
  # random color and point character
  clr <- rep("black", n)
  clr[sample(n, 1L)] <- "red"
  pch <- sample(3:4, n, TRUE)
  # return value
  ok <- clr
  plot(
    x, y,
    pch = pch, col = clr,
    cex = 3, lwd = 3,
    xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1),
    xlab = "", ylab = "",
    axes = FALSE, frame.plot = FALSE,
    asp = 1L
  )
  click <- identify(x, y, n = 1L)
  if(off) dev.off(which = dev.cur())
  c(color = clr[click])
}

set.seed(2023)
test2()
#> color 
#> "red"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your code and your fast answer!!! It is already very close to what I would like. I still have some questions if you would be willing to answer me again.

Comment: 1. could it be programmed so that every time I run the code again, I get a different graphic? I just need alot of different graphics.

Comment: 2. the background should be completely white. I only know "Plot.new( )", is that maybe the way to do it?

Comment: 3. there should be several "X" and "+" in black as well as in red on the picture at once. The target, the red "X" should appear only sometimes and sometimes not and if then only once, so not more often on a graphic.

Comment: @Isabella Done, see if the edit answers the questions.

Comment: Wow that looks so good! You are my hero!     Is it possible to run the code several times in a row and get a different graphic each time? The X and + should always appear somewhere else. The red X should also always appear in a different position or sometimes not appear at all. @rui

Comment: I made a first attempt myself, but since I'm not an R professional but a newbie, it's pretty ridiculous compared to your code.

Comment: plot(0, xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', bty = 'n', pch = '', ylab = '', xlab = '')
mtext(".", side = 3, line = -6, adj = 0.44, cex = 2)
mtext("x", side = 1, line = 1, adj = 0.9, cex = 3)
mtext("x", side = 1, line = -10, adj = 0.5, cex = 3)
mtext("x", side = 1, line = 2, adj = -0.1, cex = 3, col = 'red')
mtext("x", side = 3, line = -4, adj = 0.3, cex = 3, col = 'red')
mtext("+", side = 1, line = -0.5, adj = 0.3, cex = 3.5)
mtext("+", side = 3, line = 0.7, adj = 0.4, cex = 3.5)
mtext("+", side = 3, line = -0.8, adj = 0.7, cex = 3.5, col = 'red')

Comment: I can change the position of the X and + but that's a lot of work for over 100 Graphics haha

Comment: @Isabella To run the function, say, 10 times you can do `replicate(10, test2())`. See the documentation for `help("replicate")`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will generate a plot like you describe. You could play around with the +/-2 to increase or decrease the chance that one of the symbols does not appear.

```r
library(tidyverse, quietly = TRUE)

set.seed(2)

Grid <- expand_grid(x = 1:3, y = 1:3) 

Grid <- tibble(
  Vis = c(rep("", times = count(Grid) - 2), "X", "X", "+", "+"),
  Colour = c(rep("", times = count(Grid) - 2), "Red", "Black", "Red", "Black"),
  Filter = sample(1:100, size = nrow(Grid) + 2)) %>%
  arrange(Filter) %>%
  head(n = nrow(Grid)) %>%
  bind_cols(Grid)

Grid %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = Colour)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Vis, group = Colour)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(NA, "#000000", "#FF5733")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Output:

[image: Output]